# How to handle change detection when I use runOutsideAngular fromEvent?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-changedetection

In my angular application I listen to `resize` event and update the breakpoint name in `breakpointChanged` subject:

```
 breakpointChanged = new Subject();

  resize$ = fromEvent(window, "resize").pipe(
    startWith(() => []),
    map(() => [window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth]),
    tap(([height, width]) => {
      const name = this.breakpoint(width);

      this.breakpointChanged.next(name);
    })
  );
```

Base on the breakpoint name I decided when the drawer should be open or not:

```
drawerOpened$ = this.breakpointChanged.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map((breakpointName) => {
      return breakpointName !== "xs"; // if it's not xs breakpoint then it's true mean it's open.
    })
  );
```

I also want to use `distinctUntilChanged` because if the breakpoint not changed I don't want to activate the stream.

And in ngOnInit I subscribe to the `resize` stream. And I do it in `runOutsideAngular`, so I wont trigger change detection every time the resize happens.

```
 this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
   this.resize$.subscribe();
 });
```

The problem is the view doesn't update.

Only when I wrap the `this.breakpointChanged.next(name);` with `this.zone.run(() => {})` it's works but if I do that I'll trigger change detection - always when the resize happens. which is bad thing.

Any idea how to solve this problem and make it nice and clean?

In the same context, how `async` pipe doesn't make change detection? the value is changing and `async` should subscribe and trigger when it's the value changes.

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-sun-o3ft2?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

That's a nice question. May be we can reduce the complexity by using `debounceTime()` as below:

```
  resize$ = fromEvent(window, "resize").pipe(
    startWith(() => []),
    debounceTime(1000),
    map(() => [window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth]),
    tap(([height, width]) => {
      console.log(height);
      const name = this.breakpoint(width);
      this.breakpointChanged.next(name);
    })
  );
```

and removing `this.zone.runOutsideAngular`

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.resize$.subscribe();
  }
```

no matter how many times it is resized, the event will be emitted after 1 second.

[Here is what I tried in your example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-dust-oqwh1?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:352-657)

Let me know if this helps

Comment: sorry my mistake for delete the question.

Comment: the `debounceTime` doesn't help because the value of the subject is changed but it not reflect the value. (which change detection is doing). 
somehow need to call change detection but can't find a way where to do it

Comment: @JonSud: please check the updated answer. I forgot to handle `this.zone.runOutsideAngular` . This should bring it back to the Angular world

Comment: Well, I add `runOutsideAngular` to not trigger CD every time  the `resize` happens. but in some events like change the breakpoint it should update the breakpointChanged stream. and because the stream it's change the async pipe should update the html in the component. this is why I use `runOutsideAngular`.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a `debounceTime(250)` as the first param of the `fromEvent(...).pipe(...)`
- Wrap the `breakpoint.next` in the `zone.run(..)` just as you were doing, and also keep the same `runOutsideAngular` approach

Change detection will run after every 250ms duration as you resize, which is what you're after - a good user experience plus limited/less change detection